# Inserting 2 VB combo box inputs into one column in my SQL server database instead of 2 separate columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to insert the value of two combo boxes into one column name Starttime and Endtime in my SqL database but I keep getting the error "String or binary data would be turncated. The statement has been terminated" I just want to SQL data to display the AM and PM values seclected from the combobox with the time and not in separate values as I have now. I tried the & to just combine the 2 combo boxes and insert them into the data but no luck.

```
Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
'myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-LFHD0UQ\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL"
'myconnect.ConnectionString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=calendar2.1;Data Source=DESKTOP-LFHD0UQ\SQLEXPRESS"
myconnect.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=calendar2.1;Data Source=DESKTOP-LFHD0UQ\SQLEXPRESS"
Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
mycommand.Connection = myconnect
mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CalendarData3 (Date,Title,Description,StartTime,EndTime,eAMPM,sAMPM) VALUES (@Date,@Title,@Description,@StartTime,@EndTime,@eAMPM,@sAMPM)"
myconnect.Open()

Try
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtDate.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = title.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = description.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = starttime.Text & sampm.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@EndTime", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = endtime.Text & eampm.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@eAMPM", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = eampm.Text
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@sAMPM", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = sampm.Text



    intRetVal = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as the field-size of the two columns "StartTime" and "EndTime" in your Database "CalendarData3" are not big enough.

Be sure they can hold Data for "starttime.Text & sampm.Text" and "endtime.Text & eampm.Text"